# How to send a ping message to show that a device is online in Cumulocity?

Tags: rest, cumulocity

I'm trying out Cumulocity right now with my Raspberry Pi and I want to setup some kind of uptime monitoring for the device and it seems Cumulocity has some possibility to add a time range in which a device normally is sending a message and therefore could alert if there wasn't a message inside this time range.

What's the best way to send some kind of *ping* message from a device to show that the device is online in Cumulocity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took me some time to figure this out (as it is not documented in the docs), so I hope this might be helpful to others facing the same problem.

The easiest way might be to send a request with an empty JSON object like this:

```
PUT /inventory/managedObjects/<device ID> HTTP/1.1
Host: <your subdomain>.cumulocity.com
Authorization: Basic <device credentials>
Content-Length: 2

{}
```

Note that it may take up some seconds to show the updated device status in Cumulocity.